# Calculating height of tree provided condition on height of left tree and height of right tree

Tags: algorithm

Suppose We denote leftheight(u) and rightheight(u) the heights of the left and the right subtrees of a node u.

Now if we have a constant c > 0 such that for all nodes u in a tree T, we have

```
leftheight(u) ≤ rightheight(u) + c
```

What can be said about the height of such tree ? Is it O(log n) or what ?

Also, if the condition had been changed to :

```
leftheight(u)−c ≤ rightheight(u) ≤ leftheight(u) + c
```

How it will affect the height of tree ?

Comment: If you were talking about `leftweight(u)` and `rightweight(u)` then we could talk about the height

Comment: @shapiro.yaacov I didnt get you

Comment: The definition of height in a tree is always  `height(u) = max(height_left_son(u), height_right_son(u))`. So either this answers your question, or it open a new discussion about what can be said when you know something about the weights of the children of `u`.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first pat of the question, the height would *not* be `O(log n)`. Consider a tree with `n` nodes which is degenerated to a a list by; for every node `u`, the left subtree is empty and each node (except the single leaf) has a nonempty right subtree, as in the following sketch.

```
 a
  \
   b
    \
     c
```

The inequality

```
leftheight(u) ≤ rightheight(u) + c
```

holds for every constant `c`, yet the height of the tree is `n`.

Comment: Whats for second case ?

Comment: So second added inequality wont alter results anyhow ?

Comment: Can you explain solution to both cases seperatly. I am not getting it like this

Comment: I'm not sure about the second case.

Comment: So above solution is only for first case. Right ?

Comment: Yes. However I would guess that for the second case, the height is bounded by `O(log n)`. Note that `c=1`, holds for [AVL trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), for which indeed the height is bounded by `O(log n)`.

Answer (score 0):

The expressions you put can be rewritten in mathematical form as ::
Ist Part :: `A ≤ B + C`
IInd Part:: `A - C ≤ B ≤ A + C`
As `C > 0` , i.e. `C` can be any positive number ,so **answer for both part is** `O(n)` .
This is because in **Ist Part** ,put `C=10` and `B=0` then `A` which is `leftheight(u)` can be **10** and hence tree's height will be **11** with **11 nodes**, which is `O(n)`.
Similarly for **IIndd part** put `C=10` and `A=0` ,so inequality will be of the form `-10≤B≤10` ,now `B=10` will satisfy this inequality and hence `B` which is `rightheight(u)` will be **10** so height of tree will become **11** ,which again is `O(n)`.